# changing the font of a slickedit _tree_view

Tags: slickedit

I have a _tree_view object
I want to change it's font
adding

p_font_name="Courier New";

property didn't cause anything to change

any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

apparently restarting the slick-edit solved the problem (there were several restarts but one of them made the new font)